Encrypted video file serving with PHP part by part (chunks)
I have this script to display videos mp4(accept ranges: bytes), it works fine, but now I have encrypted the first 102400 bytes in a mp4 file to 21528 byte encryption, and I am stuck really bad(only the first loop is encrypted). It works if I don't serve the video with bytes range(http range), but if I am using accept ranges: bytes(header), it needs some re-calculations I think. Should I modify/calculate new headers length or content range, file-buffer or the start position for byte requests,  etc?
This decryption is not working with Accept-Ranges: bytes: File bytes mismatch or something...Idk
$file = ''.$video_img_root.'newfileMFIRST.mp4';

    $content_type="video/mp4"; 
   if (file_exists($file)) {

 $timestart=time();

 $maxtimeout=$timestart+10; ////how long max seconds until request end
  $maxbuf=100; // per loop buffer in KB
 $maxloadonce=2500; // max load in one request in KB



$fp = @fopen($file, 'rb');
$size   = filesize($file); // File size
$length = $size;           // Content length
$start  = 0;               // Start byte
$end    = $size - 1;       // End byte


header('Content-type: '.$content_type.'');

header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {
    $c_start = $start;
    $c_end   = $end;
    list(, $range) = explode('=', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], 2);
    if (strpos($range, ',') !== false) {
        header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
        header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size");
        exit;
    }
    if ($range == '-') {
        $c_start = $size - substr($range, 1);
    }else{
        $range  = explode('-', $range);
        $c_start = $range[0];
        $c_end   = (isset($range[1]) && is_numeric($range[1])) ? $range[1] : $size;
    }
    $c_end = ($c_end > $end) ? $end : $c_end;
    if ($c_start > $c_end || $c_start > $size - 1 || $c_end >= $size) {
        header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
        header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size");
        exit;
    }
    $start  = $c_start;
    $end    = $c_end;
    $length = $end - $start + 1;
    fseek($fp, $start);
    header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
}
header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size");
header("Content-Length: ".$length);
    
$buffer = 1024 * $maxbuf; 
$mybuf=$buffer;
$maxonce= 1024 * $maxloadonce; // 
$s=0;
$cbuf=0;
   if ($start==0) {
            while(!feof($fp)) {
               $rfile=fread($fp, 21528);
        $encrypted2=secured_decrypt($rfile);
   echo"$encrypted2";
   break;
     }
   }
while(!feof($fp) && ($p = ftell($fp)) <= $end) {
    if ($p + $buffer > $end) {
        $buffer = $end - $p + 1;
    }
    $s=$s+1;
    $cbuf=$mybuf+$cbuf;
    echo fread($fp, $buffer);
    
    flush();

}
fclose($fp);
exit();
//file does not exists:
 } else  {
      header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
      echo"File does not exist";
    exit;
     }

This code is working even with encrypted MP4 file:
    $file = '/var/www/html/newfileMFIRST.mp4'; // first 

$content_type="video/mp4";
  $timestart=time();
 $maxtimeout=$timestart+10; ////how long max seconds until request end
$maxbuf=100; // per loop buffer in KB
  $maxloadonce=2500; // max load in one request in KB



$fp = @fopen($file, 'rb');
$size   = filesize($file); // File size
$length = $size;           // Content length
$start  = 0;               // Start byte
$end    = $size - 1;       // End byte
header('Content-type: '.$content_type.'');
//header("Accept-Ranges: 0-$length");
    
$buffer = 1024 * $maxbuf; 
$mybuf=$buffer;
$maxonce= 1024 * $maxloadonce; // 
$s=0;
$cbuf=0;
   // START decrypts first 21528 bytes, because only 21528 bytes has been encrypted in this MP4 file START
     if ($start==0) {
            while(!feof($fp)) {
               $rfile=fread($fp, 21528);
        $encrypted2=secured_decrypt($rfile); // replacing  21528 bytes content with 102400 bytes content
     echo"$encrypted2";
    break;
       }
 fseek($fp, 21528);
 }
   // END decrypts first 21528 bytes, because only 21528 bytes has been  encrypted in this MP4 file END
while(!feof($fp) && ($p = ftell($fp)) <= $end) {
    if ($p + $buffer > $end) {
        $buffer = $end - $p + 1;
    }
    $s=$s+1;
    $cbuf=$mybuf+$cbuf;
    echo fread($fp, $buffer);
    $timenow=time();
    flush();

}
fclose($fp);
exit();


"but now I have encrypted the first 102400 bytes in a mp4 file" - can you post the standard you are following? For instance, I think MPEG-DASH might have this as part of it, but it has been a while since I looked.

Above code is only restoring/decrypting and playing the MP4 file (decryption is as simple as the first number 2=88).The problem is that If I use "Accept-Ranges: bytes" headers and HTTP_RANGE it will not work, there may be some file byte differences , I added working code(video not seek-able, but plays) to clarify. Thank you for noticing!

I also noticed that there may be some problems because of bytes mismatch, first request browser makes to mp4 and the second one must be probably equal file bytes, but If I only use decrypt in the first request and not in second request then it is not playing. If I use decrypt  in both requests(bytes will be the same?) and add +21528 to $start, it will play, but this makes file distorted and wrong, since its wrong, so I probably need to compensate the bytes in range request if this even acceptable by the browser.

Finally managed to get bytes right needed both original and encrypted file sizes calculations, still not working with full encrypted files, needs more calculations, if even possible:
  $file = '/var/www/html/newfileMFIRST.mp4'; // encrypted file
   $file2 = '/var/www/html/newfile2.mp4'; // original mp4 file

    $content_type="video/mp4";

      if (file_exists($file)) {

       $timestart=time();
   ///SETTINGS
   $maxtimeout=$timestart+10; ////how long max seconds until request end
   $maxbuf=100; // per loop buffer in KB
  $maxloadonce=2500; // max load in one request in KB

      ///SETTINGS END

 $fp = @fopen($file, 'rb');
   $sizem   = filesize($file);
$size   = filesize($file2); // need the original filesize to work
 $sizedif   = $sizem-$size; // File size
$length = $size;           // Content length
$start  = 0;               // Start byte
$end    = $size - 1;   
    $end2    = $sizem - 1;     // need end
           //get the last-modified-date of this very file
       $lastModified=filemtime($file);
       //get a unique hash of this file (etag)
      //set last-modified header
      //set etag-header
           //make sure caching is turned on
        header('Content-type: '.$content_type.'');
//header("Accept-Ranges: 0-$length");
header("Accept-Ranges: bytes");
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {
    $c_start = $start;
    $c_end   = $end;
    list(, $range) = explode('=', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], 2);
    if (strpos($range, ',') !== false) {
        header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
        header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size");
        exit;
    }
    if ($range == '-') {
        $c_start = $size - substr($range, 1);
    }else{
        $range  = explode('-', $range);
        $c_start = $range[0];
        $c_end   = (isset($range[1]) && is_numeric($range[1])) ? $range[1] : $size;
    }
    $c_end = ($c_end > $end) ? $end : $c_end;
    if ($c_start > $c_end || $c_start > $size - 1 || $c_end >= $size) {
        header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
        header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size");
        exit;
    }
    $start  = $c_start;
    $end    = $c_end;
    $length = $end - $start + 1;
    header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
}
header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size");
header("Content-Length: ".$length);
    
$buffer = 1024 * $maxbuf; 
$mybuf=$buffer;
$maxonce= 1024 * $maxloadonce; // 
$s=0;
$cbuf=0;
       if ($start == 0) {

                while(!feof($fp)) {
               $rfile=fread($fp, 21528);
        $encrypted2=secured_decrypt($rfile);
    echo $encrypted2;
      flush();
        break;
     }
     fseek($fp, 21528);

      } else {
       fseek($fp, $start+$sizedif);
          }
      while(!feof($fp) && ($p = ftell($fp)) <= $end2) {
    if ($p + $buffer > $end2) {
        $buffer = $end2 - $p + 1;
    }
    echo fread($fp, $buffer);
    flush();

     }
fclose($fp);
exit();
//file does not exists:
 } else  {
      header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
      echo"File does not exist";
    exit;
     }

